# what does "show somebody the door" meaning?

Tags: meaning

I read a comic here: https://xkcd.com/1357/

I found the last picture says "and they're showing you the door"

is that a proverb? what does it mean?

[image: https://xkcd.com/1357/]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the person doing the door-showing wants the other person to leave. It's worded as though the door-shower is doing something positive